# directive not properly being targeted by jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been playing around a bit with [this slick jQuery datpicker](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date.htm) and wanted to wrap it up as a directive that I could use inside my angular app. The code for the directive is very simple for right now:

```
directive('datePicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input type="text" class="topcoat-text-input--large full" placeholder="Select Date">',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.pickadate();
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm simply targeting the element parameter with the necessary `pickadate()` jQuery call. The input is properly being targeted as when I click on it I am provided with the datepicker interface and can interact with it no problem. However, when I select a date no information is being populated into the input element. Am I missing something obvious that will allow the date being selected from the control to set the value of the input?

I've done a little bit of debugging and in the link function the element parameter seems to be wrapping the actual input in some way (there seems to be a childNodes array property that holds the `<input>` tag). Could this be why I'm getting the popup for the picker but the selected value isn't being set as the input's value?

Comment: create demo in jsfiddle.net or plunker that replicates problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element` is the original element in your markup. By default it is not replaced and template is used for innerHtml.

You could use `replace:true` option in directive or `element.find('input').pickadate()`

Either of these should resolve visual issue of seeing date. One important thing to note however when you use `ng-model` and change a value from external code like a jQuery plugin, will need to use the plugin `select` ( or whatever it is called in pluginAPI) callback to trigger `scope.$apply()`. This infomrs angular a change was made from code external to angular and to update internals

Comment: Awesome! Adding replace:true did the trick for getting the date the user selected to show up in the input. Do you happen to know of any good resources or tutorials that talk about the second thing you mentioned in regards to the ng-model being changed externally? I'm still new to all this and sounds a bit confusing

Comment: general rule of thumb...if you change a scope value from external code like a jQuery plugin, angular is unaware of it and won't run a digest so need to use `$.apply`. Should find a fair bit in google search

Comment: read everyhting you can in docs site about dirctives. They are extremely powerful but have a fairly big learning curve

Comment: I think I lucked out this time as the plugin I was using exposed an onSet function that I could use to trigger input after a value was selected. I was able to use this so that angular could be notified of a value change.

Comment: exactly...a good plugin will always expose events....always look for that when chosing one...as well as good docs

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should add `replace: true` to your directive definition - Angular is targeting the `<date-picker>` directive element instead of the input.

Instead you can also try this: `element.children().first().pickadate();`